# transmute a large data frame into 3 columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1), b1=c(0,0,0,0), b2=c(0,0,0,0),c1=c(0,0,1,0), 
                 c2=c(0,1,0,0), e=c(0,0,0,0), d=c(0,0,0,0))
```

> ```
>   a b1 b2 c1 c2 d e
> 1 1 0   0 0  0  0 0
> 2 1 0   0 0  1  0 0
> 3 1 0   0 1  0  0 0
> 4 1 0   0 0  0  0 0
> ```

How can I transmute these into 3 columns into ab=a * sum(contains("b")) ac=a * (sum(contains("c")))

I am looking for something similar to `transmute(df, ab=a*(sum(b1+b2)), ac=a*(sum(c1+c2)), aothers=a*(sum (!contains ("a" | "b" | "c")))`

ab: `a * sum(any col that contains "b")`

ac: `a * sum(any col that contains "c")`

aothers: `a * sum(contains anything but a or b or c)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A base R solution:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ab = df$a * rowSums(df[, grepl("b", names(df))]),
                  ac = df$a * rowSums(df[, grepl("c", names(df))]),
                  others = df$a * rowSums(df[, !grepl("a|b|c", names(df))]))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df2
>   ab ac others
> 1  0  0      0
> 2  0  1      0
> 3  0  1      0
> 4  0  0      0
> ```

An alternative base R solution:

```
p <- c("b","c")
v <- c("others", paste0("a", p))

s <- sapply(p, grepl, x = names(df)[-1])

collist <- split.default(df[-1], v[rowSums(s * col(s)) + 1L])

l <- lapply(collist, function(x) df$a * rowSums(x))

df2 <- as.data.frame(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be simpler to manage if we convert the data to long format, create a new column to separate "b", "c" and "others" column, `group_by` each and multiply with "a" values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(a, row)) %>%
  mutate(col = case_when(grepl('b', name) ~"ab", 
                         grepl('c', name) ~"ac", 
                         TRUE ~ "others")) %>%
  group_by(row, col) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value * a)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row) 

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#     ab    ac others
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     0     0      0
#2     0     1      0
#3     0     1      0
#4     0     0      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R solution with `cbind()` + `grep()`+ `rowSums()`

```
nms <- names(df)
dfout <- cbind(df[1],
               `colnames<-`(df$a*cbind(rowSums(df[grep("b",nms)]), 
                                       rowSums(df[grep("c",nms)]), 
                                       rowSums(df[grep("^[^abc]",nms)])),
                            c("ab","ac","others")))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  a ab ac others
1 1  0  0      0
2 1  0  1      0
3 1  0  1      0
4 1  0  0      0
```